# How to notify the user with an alert sound every week from my application?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
[localNotification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600]];
[localNotification setAlertAction:@"Launch"];
[localNotification setAlertBody:[alertBodyField text]];
[localNotification setHasAction: YES];
[localNotification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
[alertNotification setHidden:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here list of Repeat Time Interval:**

Specify calendrical units such as day and month.

```
enum {
   NSEraCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitEra,
   NSYearCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitYear,
   NSMonthCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitMonth,
   NSDayCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitDay,
   NSHourCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitHour,
   NSMinuteCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitMinute,
   NSSecondCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitSecond,
   NSWeekCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitWeek,
   NSWeekdayCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitWeekday,
   NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal,
   NSQuarterCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitQuarter,
   NSWeekOfMonthCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth,
   NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitWeekOfYear,
   NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear
   NSCalendarCalendarUnit = (1 << 20),
   NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit = (1 << 21),
};
typedef NSUInteger NSCalendarUnit;
```

**In Your case :**

Setting your repeat interval to `'NSWeekCalendarUnit'` should do the trick. It repeats on a weekly basis on the same day and time as the original notification.

FOr Set Sound of Notification:

```
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName; // Here you can also use custom sound .
```

For custom sound

```
localNotification.soundName = @"alarm_sound.wav";// put name of sound file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
[localNotification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600]];
[localNotification setAlertAction:@"Launch"];
[localNotification setAlertBody:[alertBodyField text]];
[localNotification setHasAction: YES];

// change
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;    // set the repeat interval
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName; // set alert sound

[localNotification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
[alertNotification setHidden:NO];
```